# Python use a dict with value-types str, int, attribute and nested attribute in a different module

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, attributes, python-import

I have a module (module2) which contains a single function:

```
#module2
def get_items():
    return {'thing1': 'string_value',
            'thing2': 1,
            'thing3': 'self.foo1',
            'thing4': 'self.foo2.bar',
            'thing5': 'self.foo3.bar['some_key']'}
```

As can be seen, the dictionary keys are strings, the values include strings and integers, but also attributes (i.e. `self.foo1`), nested attributes (i.e. `self.foo2.bar`) and dict references within a nested attribute (i.e. `self.foo3.bar['some_key']`) written as strings. They are written as strings because there is no self in the context of module2, rather I would like to import this dictionary into another module (module1) and reference some self.

I am aware that I can access the attributes via `getattr(self, value.split('self.')[1]`.
I have set up a recursive function to get nested attributes which is called "rgetattr" in the code below.

The only thing I can't figure out is how to deal with the nested dictionary.

Concretely, I would like the following behaviour:

```
#module2
def get_items():
    return {'thing1': 'string_value',
            'thing2': 1,
            'thing3': 'self.foo1',
            'thing4': 'self.foo2.bar',
            'thing5': 'self.foo3.bar['some_key']'} 

#module1
Class my_class:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo # Note that this foo is an object

        ### The following is how I would like the imported dictionary to look ###
        my_desired_dict = {'thing1': 'string_value',
                           'thing2': 1,
                           'thing3': self.foo1,
                           'thing4': self.foo2.bar
                           'thing5': self.foo3.bar['some_key']}

        ### The following is how I am attempting to achieve this ###
        import module2
        item_dict = module2.get_items()

        my_desired_dict = {}

        for i in item_dict:
            if type(item_dict[i])==str and item_dict[i].startswith('self.'):
                    variable = item_dict[i].split('self.')[1]
                    this_attr = rgetattr(self, variable)
            else:
                 this_attr = item_dict[i]
            my_desired_dict[i] = this_attr



    def rgetattr(obj, attr, *args):
        def _getattr(obj, attr):
            return getattr(obj, attr, *args)
        return functools.reduce(_getattr, [obj] + attr.split('.'))
```

I would be open to changing the "attribute reference strings" in module2 to simply self.foo etc if there were a way to do this without triggering a NameError.

Comment: This seems really convoluted and the result of a poor design decision. I suspect there is a far far easier way of getting the effect you describe. I'm sure what you're asking for can be done -- but I wouldn't do it.

Comment: For example, in `module2` have `def get_items: return {'thing1': lambda self: 'string_value', ..., 'thing3': lambda self: self.foo1, ...}`. Then you can make `my_desired_dict = {k: v(self) for k, v in module2.get_items().items()}`.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you need to write a simple parser for your format; there’s no builtin function that can split on dots and also split out brackets parts and return something you can just reduce over. Since your format is actually a subset of the Python expression language, you can cheat and use `ast.parse` as your parser and write a function that takes a start value to substitute and a parse tree and recursively walks the tree (or uses the `ast` module to walk it for you) transforming the start value by attribution and subscription, raising a ValueError for any unexpected nodes.

Comment: Indeed, @FHTMitchel, using lambdas worked for me.

Comment: @abarnert answered my question more specifically, though it seems that my question was inherently overcomplicated.